# Eclipse RCP plugin error - Cannot resolve module

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dependencies, rcp

When I try to run a eclipse product like this:

[image: Running_an_Eclipse_Product.png]

I get about 100 errors type "Could not resolve module XXXX". For example, a partial log view:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.compare 4 0 2017-07-14 11:03:53.679
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.compare [18]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.views; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.views; bundle-version="3.8.100.v20160518-1929"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.views [107]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.108.0.v20160518-1929"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui [99]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.108.0.v20160602-1232"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.ui.workbench [109]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"; bundle-version="0.14.0.v20160523-1900"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                            org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [52]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.event; resolution:="optional"
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.extender; filter:="(&(osgi.extender=osgi.component)(version>=1.2)(!(version>=2.0)))"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt
                         -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"; bundle-version="0.14.0.v20160525-0940"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                            org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [51]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"
                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.14.0.v20160523-1900"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor; bundle-version="3.10.0.v20160530-2011"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor [110]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.108.0.v20160518-1929"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.editors; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.editors; bundle-version="3.10.0.v20160505-0931"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.editors [101]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.12.0.v20160601-1609"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui.ide [103]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.106.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.108.0.v20160518-1929"; singleton:="true"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.7.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.108.0.v20160602-1232"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.108.0.v20160518-1929"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.12.0.v20160601-1609"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1599)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

I think that it's because the plugin cannot detect the needed dependencies.
I have tried adding those dependencies in

> Run Configurations > Plug-ins Tab > Add Required Plug-ins

like many users post, but it doesn't work properly. I mean, new dependencies are added, but the errors don't disappear.

I have also tried downloading the libraries .jar files and including them into the project, but it doesn't work properly too.

Can you help me, please?

My objetive is to generate a binary file or an executable file to run an Eclipse RCP Plugin.

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe try adding `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` as a dependency. More info [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494913)

Comment: Thanks for your answer titou10 ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem while using a "***.target***" file as target platform, you can specify the plug-in `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` in the section "***Implicit Plug-in Dependencies***" section of the "***Environment***" tab.

[image]